# Firestore batch write using loops

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write batch date data using for loops but it didn't work though the console says otherwise. I think it's only updated in firebase console for the last iteration only. I have tried for 2 days and don't know what is what anymore !

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault()
const stdRoom = firebase.firestore().collection("stdRoom").doc()
let i;
let momentDate = moment("June 7 2020").startOf("day")._d

for ( i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
  stdRoom.set({avail: 7, date: momentDate })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });

  momentDate = moment(momentDate).add(1,"d").startOf("day")._d
  console.log(momentDate)
}
```

I have tried batch() and commit after exiting loop but no avail. Im using momentjs for date handling. If I do one by one then it worked.

It's a hotel room. I want to set availability for a std room for 10 days in this case with availability of 7 for each day and maybe 365 days. Any solution please? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to write different data to the same map fields in the same document? Unless I am understanding wrong the correct behavior of this would be that only the last iteration would persist since you are overwriting the previous data with each loop.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain the behavior you're expecting that's different than what you're observing.  Just saying "it doesn't work" isn't likely to get you much help.  What's your final goal here?

Comment: Pardon me - a newbie. it's a hotel room. I want to set availability for a std room for 10 days in this case with availability of 7 for each day. Any elegant solution?

Comment: Could you edit the question to *be more specific* and describe what you expect the final state of the database to look like?  Your code is, in fact, just writing a single document with a random ID 7 times.  What are you expecting to be different?

Comment: Thanks Doug. Didn't realized it was writing to the same document. Finally managed to get them in with setInterval and .add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing to the same document:

```
const stdRoom = firebase.firestore().collection("stdRoom").doc()
```

In a for loop:

```
for ( i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
  stdRoom.set({avail: 7, date: momentDate })
```

Firestore limits document writes to 1 per second and this for loop will violate that restriction. See Writes and Transactions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that it got 1 second limit ! Finally managed to insert the data. using setInterval and .add instead.

Comment: Yeah I went through a lot of pain one day before I figured out the write limit! The limit makes sense but it will drive you nuts if you don't know about it.